# Is INNER JOIN + INSERT INTO TABLE faster than UNION ALL in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, insert-into, union-all

I have a query for a list of genes and I am doing an INNER JOIN to retrieve the results that matches those genes in a database ([EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVRZA.png)):

```
SELECT t1.*, database1.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN database1
ON t1.GeneSymbol = database1.GeneSymbol;
```

I have multiple databases that contains interactions of genes with different number of rows (varies from 5,000 to 70,000,000 rows) and I would like to add up all the rows together that match. I have tried to perform an simple UNION ALL instead of a INNER JOIN like the following:

```
SELECT t1.*, database1.*
FROM t1, database1
WHERE t1.GeneSymbol = database1.GeneSymbol

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.*, database2.*
FROM t1, database2
WHERE t1.GeneSymbol = database2.GeneSymbol;
```

However, If I try to add up more and more databases using UNION ALL to merge the results, it would take forever. I was wondering if doing an `INNER JOIN` + `INSERT INTO TABLE`  for all the databases and inserting the output in a table with the correct number of columns, would it go a lot faster ?

Comment: Have you tuned either query, e.g. by considering the indices on the tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes I indexed all the columns of tables on which I am querying my list my genes.

Comment: If you already have indices on the columns involved in the `WHERE` clause and join columns, then just benchmark both approaches and see how they scale.  It doesn't matter what anyone says here, it only matters what is fastest with your data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was asking to see if there was really a difference between the two ways. So I guess it does depend on my data, right ? Anyway, thanks for the reply

Comment: They also don't generate the same output, but you probably already know this.

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't just try it yourself and see?

Comment: @underscore_d I would have tried it but I am currently away from my workplace. I just though about how I could process my data and I wanted to know some opinions about it.